# write a PLSQL block which will throw an exception if there is no record available in department table for the dept_id in emp table

Tags: plsql

schema details:

```
Table   columns
dept    dept_head, dept_id,dept_name  ::::::
emp     dept_id, emp_id,emp_lname, emp_status, loc_id, ...
```

output format:

```
Dept ID :**** is not a valid ID
```

I have tried with this code in HackerRank, getting the desired output still not able to pass the testcase. it says incorrect answer, testcase 0 failed. can anyone suggest me where i am making mistake and help me in passing the testcase.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
DEPTID emp.DEPT_ID%type:=123;
DEPTNAME dept.DEPT_NAME%type;
DEPTHEAD dept.DEPT_HEAD%type;
begin
select DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME,DEPT_HEAD into DEPTID,DEPTNAME,DEPTHEAD from dept where DEPT_ID=DEPTID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DEPTID || DEPTNAME || DEPTHEAD);
Exception
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID :'||DEPTID||' is not a valid ID');  
END;
/
exit;
```

Comment: [NO_DATA_FOUND](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-8C327B4A-71FA-4CFB-8BC9-4550A23734D6) is a pre-defined exception in PL/SQL. You don't need to add exception handling code. However, you can explicitly [raise an exception](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-66346B68-7A18-438C-951B-A60F970D98B8)

Comment: The test seems to require you to raise an exception, but your code doesn't.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *"no record available in department table for the dept_id in emp table"*. Which dept_id in the emp table? You mean emp rows whose dept_id is not present in dept? A link to the hackerrank question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it in principle:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select distinct dept_id from emp
    )
    loop
        select dept_id into r.dept_id
        from   dept
        where  dept_id = r.dept_id;
    end loop;
end;
```

A link to the Hackerrank question would be helpful to confirm what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is --

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
DEPTID emp.DEPT_ID%type:=60;
DEPTNAME dept.DEPT_NAME%type;
DEPTHEAD dept.DEPT_HEAD%type;
begin
select DEPT_ID,DEPT_NAME,DEPT_HEAD into DEPTID,DEPTNAME,DEPTHEAD from dept where DEPT_ID=DEPTID;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DEPTID || DEPTNAME || DEPTHEAD);
Exception
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID :'||DEPTID||' is not a valid ID');  
END;
/
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
EMP_DEPTID emp.DEPT_ID%type;
DEPT_DEPTID DEPT.DEPT_ID%type;
cursor c is
select * from emp;
begin
for i in c loop
EMP_DEPTID:=i.DEPT_ID;
select d.DEPT_ID INTO DEPT_DEPTID FROM DEPT d where d.DEPT_ID=i.DEPT_ID;
end loop;

Exception
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID :'||EMP_DEPTID||' is not a valid ID');  
END;
/
```

Comment: Please write a bit about what you've done and why this is an answer. :-)